Is $f(x):=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }(n!)^x \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{(k+x)!}$ a Gaussian curve?
In this question I was trying to generalise the gamma function and defined $f(x+1)= g(x+1)f(x)$ for some function $g$ such that $g$ is eventually non negative function, To make it clear that $f$ depends on $x$ and $g$ I will write $f$ as $\Pi(x, g(t))$, $\Pi(x, t)$ is just the ordinary pi function.
I conjectured that :
$$\Pi(x, g(t)) = \lim_{n \to \infty } g(n)^x \prod\limits_{1\le k\le n} \frac{g(k)}{g(k+x)} $$
I tried to graph $\Pi(x, t!)$ or in other words $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }(n!)^x \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{(k+x)!}$ and it looks like it approaching a Gaussian curve, this is a graph of $\Pi(x, t!)$ when $n=100$:

Desmos seems to have a trouble graphing any number greater than $150$ because $n!^x$ increases very quickly.
I tried to prove that    $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }(n!)^x \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{(k+x)!}$ is in the form of $ae^{-\left(\frac{x-b}{c} \right)^2}$ but I didn't reach anything useful.

$$
\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k^{ - 1/2}k! }}{{(k - 1/2)!}}}  \ge \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{8k}}} \right)}  \ge Cn^{1/8}
$$ In general, it will tend to $0$ for $x>0$ and $x<-1$, to $1$ for $x=0$ and $x=-1$, and to $+\infty$ for $-1<x<0$. You can deduce this from the asymptotics $$
\frac{{k^x k!}}{{(k + x)!}} = 1 - \frac{{x(x + 1)}}{{2k}} + \mathcal{O}!\left( {\frac{{x^4 }}{{k^2 }}} \right)
$$ for large $k$ and fixed $x$.

@Gary. Can we do anything using the Barnes G function ? Just curious.
